# Next and previos images mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a script that lets you go navigate (next and prev) through images. Here's what I have so far, but it doesnt work.

table: `images`

row: `imageID`

row: `image_name` => this is to build a link to view the image.

```
$currentid = $row['imageID'];
$query = "SELECT imageID as prev 
          FROM images WHERE imageID < '$currentid' 
          ORDER by imageID DESC LIMIT 1;";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Unable to read table : $query");
$list = array();
while ($image = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $list[] = $image["imageID"];
}

$current_item = array_search($id1,$list);
$prev_link = $next_link = "";

if ($current_item > 0) {
    // do previous link with $list[$current_item - 1]
}
if ($current_item < sizeof($list)-1) {
    // do next link with $list[$current_item + 1]
}
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: im new to mysql, php so i dont really understand..

Comment: i did, but i barely know the older mysql.

Comment: It would be valuable to learn the basics.

Comment: @VladL Good! That means you have less to unlearn as you study the newer, more secure methods of database access FreshPrinceOfSO pointed out to you. Since the `mysql_*` functions are currently deprecated and will soon be removed from new versions of PHP, you're going to have to switch anyway; why not do so now, when the effort involved is minimal?

Comment: Wait, removed? So i will have to recode my whole script using mysqli? Everyone else to?

Comment: are imageID and image_name on rows or columns in a row?

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on? Generating the links? The query fails? The query doesn't yield the expected results?
As I can see you're fetching a single result, then trying to iterate the result as if you have several records. ALso, in the query you're fetching the imageId as `prev` and then trying to access it later as `imageId` in your code..